Working directory weirdness, no module named 'tools'?
I'm really unclear about Python, imports, and working directory.
I'm running python from my root directory, which contains a folder tools and within that, two python files: tool.py and env.py.
My python run command is: python tools/tool.py, and within tool.py I have:
import os
print("Current working directory:",os.getcwd())
from tools.env import setup_env

I'm getting an error ModuleNotFOundError: No module named 'tools'.
Am i misunderstanding something here? The print statement shows the working directory is the root directory, so shouldn't I be able to import from the tools directory? I've tried putting __init__.py in the tools directory, didn't fix it.

you're already in the tools folder so maybe you should try from .env import setup_env

Try import env.setup_env. Since you're working in tools, I don't see how you could go back up your tree (Unless you edit the path using os or something). Importing from another file in the same directory shouldn't need the parent folder in the import statement.

If you print sys.path, you will see that the tools subfolder is included. So try from env import setup_env. Python imports - the gift that keeps on giving.
